# Why can't I write to a file if it is located within an if statement?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a very simple program that writes to a file, but can't understand why it won't let me write to a file if I put it within an if statement! Here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
void readFile();

int main()
{
    string line;
    string today;
    string readOrWrite;

    cout << "Do you want to write to a file or read a file? " << endl;
    cout << "Type \"write\" or \"read\" ";
    cin >> readOrWrite;

    if (readOrWrite == "read")
    {
        readFile();
    }
    else if (readOrWrite == "write")
    {
        cout << "How are you today? " << endl;
        getline(cin, today);

        ofstream myJournal;
        myJournal.open("Journal.txt", ios::app);
        myJournal << today << " ";
        myJournal.close();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
void readFile()
{
    ifstream myJournal;
    myJournal.open("Journal.txt");
    string line;

    if (myJournal.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(myJournal, line))
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        myJournal.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file ";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

When I move it out of the if statement, it works smoothly and is able to write to the file, but when I place it inside, it opens the program, asks me the **"Do you want to write to a file or read a file? "**, I type "write", then it says **"How are you today? "** and then ends the program, printing **"Press any key to continue..."**. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't that `cin >> readOrWrite;` leaves a newline in the input buffer, and `getline` reads that? Try adding `cin.ignore(1000, '\n');` before the `getline`...

Comment: @MatsPetersson Ahh yes that seemed to do it. Why would getline read that if I stated it to only read getline(cin, today)?

Comment: @Cjolsen06 `getline` means to read all characters up to (and including) a newline. The first character it found was a newline so its job is done. BTW you should observe that `Journal.txt` has a space appended to it , as opposed to your claim that it did not write to the file.

Comment: @Cjolsen06 cin >> readOrWrite` reads a single word, and leaves anything else in the stream, which in your case is a newline from pressing 'Enter' after typing the response. The simplest fix is just to use `getline(cin, readOrWrite)` to read the first response, as that will consume the newline character, so you don't need to mess about with `ignore`

Comment: @JonathanWakely I checked the current standard version and it does in fact specify that `ios::app` is equivalent to `ios::app | ios::out`

Comment: @M.M that has always been the case. And as I said, `ofstream` ORs it with `out` anyway.

Comment: @JonathanWakely in C++03 `ios:app` by itself was invalid for `fstream::open`, I also checked that standard document. You're right about `ofstream` applying `out`.

Comment: @M.M that was just a defect, http://wg21.link/lwg596 _"at least two current implementation as well as in Classic Iostreams corresponds to the C stdio "a" mode and has been traditionally documented as implying ios::out"_

Comment: @JonathanWakely OK good link. Does "CD1 status" apply retroactively? Perhaps there were some other C++03 implementations that followed the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it says "How are you today? " and then ends the program, printing "Press any key to continue...". Any help?

`std::istream::ignore` should help in that case you are encountering.

```
cout << "How are you today? " << endl;
cin.ignore(10, '\n'); // Inserted
getline(cin, today);
```

Why do we need that in between?

It takes out 10 characters, which is enough amount of length,  from the buffer and stops if it encounters a newline, which is '\n'. (Remember that you press the key 'enter' after typing "wrtie")

By doing so you can move on to the next new line, preventing `std::cin` from any parse failure.

More info : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/